# Is there any similar function in spark RDD like the 'like' function in sql?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm looking for a *RDD* operation like `like` in sql. Say I have a column with different IPs like:

```
192.168.1.1/
192.168.1.2/
192.168.1.3/
123.123.123.123/
1.1.1.1/
2.2.2.2/
```

Assume they are in a different type *RDD* and *DataFrame*, so that we can have some operations directly on them. Is there an operation that has the same outcome in *RDD* like the following sql?

```
'SELECT count(host)  from webIP  where host like '192.168.1.%'.
```

I know how to use the `reduceByKey` function to count such as `Lines.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)`, what I am looking for is a similar function like the `like` in sql to find out the IPs that start with 192.168.1.* in *RDD* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With an RDD:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['192.168.1.1',
                      '192.168.1.2',
                      '192.168.1.3',
                      '123.123.123.123',
                      '1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2'])
```

To count the elements that start with `192.168.1.` you can do:

```
>>> rdd.filter(lambda x: x.startswith('192.168.1.')).count()
3
```

beware that `filter()` is a transformation, while `count()` is an action

## With a dataframe:

you can filter with sql directly:

```
>>> the_dataframe.filter('webIP LIKE "192.168.1.%"').count()
```

assuming the target column is `'webIP'`